# how access value of array list on Struts framework by properties file

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

```
arraylist.add(new ListItem("Activity1", "ActivityName1"));
```

suppose ActivityName1 value store in properties file to provide locale feature.

now how can i access the value of Activity1 key that associate to ActivityName1 value on jsp ( ActivityName1 corresponds to a properties file value) by using Struts.

i want to find the ActivityName1 value that store in properties file by using the Activity1 key in Struts framework.

Comment: Do you mean there is not ArrayList?? Its just key/value pair in properties file.

Comment: BTW, you are using both the tags, `struts` and `struts2`. So tell us which one exactly, only their names sounds similar, but actually, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

For example if your struts property file defined as follows,

```
ActivityName1=Activity Name 1 Value in English
```

inside the JSP file simply you can access it as follows,

```
<s:label value="%{getText('ActivityName1')}"/>
```

And to iterate through your ArrayList in the JSP file you can use the  tag. And following is an simple example,

ListItem bean class

```
public class ListItem {
    private String listKey;
    private String listValue;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Inside Action class

```
// defined in action calss with getters and setters
private List<ListItem> listItems;

// inside method in action class
listItems.add(new ListItem("Activity1","ActivityName1"));
......
```

inside JSP file

```
<s:iterator value="listItems">
    <s:property value="%{getText('listKey')}"/>
    <s:property value="%{getText('listValue')}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

By combining these tips I think you will find a solution for your question....

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use hashmap..And add that map to the array list..Use