# using internationalization on list data

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

i am using Struts2 in application.

```
<s:iterator value="listObject">
<s:component template="abc.vm"> 
    <s:param name="text" value="listValue" /> 
    <s:param name="prefix" value="listIndex" /> 
</s:component>  
</s:iterator>
```

listValue is a values of list. i am using iterator to traverse the list.
now on listValue, i want to put here internationalization concept.so that all the list value can be display based on Locale which store in a list.
please suggest!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question... I assume that what you store in that list, are strings to be displayed. And you want to display them using specific language, right? If that's the case, you can treat these strings as keys and look up the value in resource file.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913674/how-access-value-of-array-list-on-struts-framework-by-properties-file) is the same question... please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

As it's explained in the [Struts 2 reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html), you can use different solutions to suporting internationalization.

I think that the best solution could fit for your requirements could be to use the `getText()` method to get the value of the resource bundle of every element of the iterator.

Other easy option can be to set the right localization value in the Action, using the same approach setting the values in the iterator before the control arrives to the UI layer.